# How can a condition in ngIf be true only for the selected row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am developing an angular project using Angular version 7. I have a table that shows some json objects. In each json object, I added 2 buttons, which I show conditionally when each one is selected.

What I mean is, when I click the Edit button, I want the No Edit button to be shown and vice versa ONLY FOR THE ROW I PRESSED THE BUTTON. But what is happening is that when I click the Edit button for a specific row, then all other buttons for the other rows change.

How can I do this?

**myapp.component.html** file:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" translate>Name</th>
        <th scope="col" translate>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor=" let product of products">
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{datasource.description}}</td>
        <td>
          <button *ngIf="allowEdit" (click)="edit(product)">
            Edit
          </button>&nbsp;
          <button *ngIf="allowNoEdit" (click)="noEdit(product)">
            No Edit
          </button>&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**myapp.component.ts** file:

```
allowEdit: boolean = true;
allowNoEdit: boolean = false;

edit(product) {
   this.allowEdit= !this.allowEdit;
   this.allowNoEdit= !this.allowNoEdit;
}

noEdit(product) {
   this.allowEdit= !this.allowEdit;
   this.allowNoEdit= !this.allowNoEdit;
}
```

Comment: You have to add *ngIf for each row, for eg. *ngIf="product.allowEdit", then you can toggle that in you click method, allowEdit and noEdit to work for selected product, product.edit = !product.edit, that should work for each row.

Comment: @mocni_T can you give example code? thanks

Comment: check my code down

Comment: I would use CSS. When clicking the edit button I would add a class to the row. This class cause the edit button to disappear an the noedit button to appear. When clicking the noedit button you then remove the css class from the row

Comment: @schlonzo I would not. It is recommended to use `*ngIf` whenever possible in order to avoid unnecessary checks performed by angular.

Comment: Using css won't cause additional checks by angular. But of course you can use `*ngIf` if you prefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myapp.component.html file:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" translate>Name</th>
        <th scope="col" translate>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor=" let product of products">
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{datasource.description}}</td>
    <td>
      <button *ngIf="!product.showEdit" (click)="allowEdit(product)">
        Edit
      </button>&nbsp;
      <button  *ngIf="product.showEdit"(click)="noEdit(product)">
        No Edit
      </button>&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and inside your typescript

```
allowEdit(product) { 
     // in case you want to close all others editing products
     this.products.forEach(product => product.showEdit = false);
     product.showEdit = true;
}

noEdit(product) { 
     product.showEdit = false;
}
```

You can check it on this link: https://codepen.io/Mocni/pen/PrProv

Comment: I press the button. It shows the other one but only for 3 seconds. Then without pressing again the same button is shown

Comment: @KathrineHanson do you want to show only one "No edit" button at a time??

Comment: well if you change data ( products) all the time property to show visibily will change... can you add code for adding products ? You can see this demo is working when you work with loaded data.

Comment: Actually I found out what was the problem. I am also sorry. I am using an Output and emit with the EventEmitter the output to update another component. When I am putting the EventMitter, then it does not work. Without it, it works. Thanks again.

Comment: @mocni_T hi. is there any other way to do this? I think this approach is not good since it is changing the structure of product object.

Answer (score 0):

What about including the condition of showing such buttons as part of the json object? when clicking edit, you can modify then the flag of the specific json object (row) and show whatever you need

Initialize for every product a `product.allowEdit = false`. Then your `Edit` button would call an `allowEdit(product)()` function where you would change the flag inside `product.allowEdit = !product.allowEdit;`

Comment: No. Do not like this approach. But Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: don't know why to suggest a function calling, when it can be handled on DOM side itself.

Comment: @shikhar I guess because that's the approach the OP is following. Personally I always try to make the least possible changes to the OP code. Maybe he/she is doing some more stuff in the functions in the real code (most probably this is just a demo). However it is true many times it is not possible to follow his/her approach because the solution needs to be seen from another perspective.

Answer (score -1):

You can dynamically add condition as "editable" key to your **product** object and check condition for making it editable or you can check on the already existing condition on product
 and your html will be

if you added **editable** key as boolean values to your object, so your html can be

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor=" let product of products">
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{datasource.description}}</td>
    <td>
      <button *ngIf="product.editable" (click)="allowEdit(product)">
        Edit
      </button>&nbsp;
      <button *ngIf="product.editable" (click)="noEdit(product)">
        No Edit
      </button>&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

or if your object contains any generic value for all the list where button should be active:

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor=" let product of products">
<td>{{product.name}}</td>
<td>{{datasource.description}}</td>
<td>
  <button *ngIf="product.somecondition" (click)="allowEdit(product)">
    Edit
  </button>&nbsp;
  <button *ngIf="product.somecondition" (click)="noEdit(product)">
    No Edit
  </button>&nbsp;
</td>
```

Comment: thats exactly what the other two answers say

Comment: well i must say they were quick doesn't mean approach is wrong